WooCommerce My account additional sections permalinks issue
I have a WordPress website with Woocommerece and Jet plugins and I purchased a theme,
I'm trying to enable multiple segments in my website but it doesn't work, and I think it's an issue related to the settings of my WordPress website and not the plugins,
I have these paths each one created by another plugin and they work:
/myaccount/view-license-keys/
/myaccount/affiliate-dashboard/
But when I'm trying to access the following paths it leads me to an empty white page only with my header and footer:
/myaccount/view-license-keys/1 (single license key page)
/myaccount/affiliate-dashboard/payments (payments page I access through the navigation menu created by the plugin)
They used to work in my older path that has "my-account" and not "myaccount" but when I changed the main myaccount design and its path I started to face this problem.
I went over the settings of WordPress, the "License Manager" plugin, the "YITH Affiliates" plugin, and the "options permalink" of WordPress and I didn't manage to solve it.

Try to regenerate permalinks by going to WordPress Settings > Permalinks, then click on "Save changes". It could solve the issue.

Thank you, I actually tried it a few times and it didn't work,
Now I trying to save it again using a custom link with /%postman%/ and keep getting back to sample-host, maybe it's an issue from WordPress side.
